# Issue with Advanced MSI and products listing Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch, cataloginventory, product-reindexing

I'm facing an issue with Magento 2.4.x, the website is hosted on managed magento server.
We have 2 inventory sources (default & abc) and we have assigned products to the source abc. If we enable the configuration to display out of stock products the category and brand listing are working perfect. But if we do not allow Display Out of Stock products, the listings are not working. We are using **Advanced MSI and Calurates module** from Amasty.
I already tried restarting elastic-search but it did not fix the issue.

Tried reindex and flush cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento "cache:clean"
php bin/magento cache:flush;redis-cli -h redis flushall;
/usr/share/stratus/cli cache.all.clear
/usr/share/stratus/cli autoscaling.reinit
```

If anybody has a solution for this issue. Please let me know.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Porto theme and theme's layered navigation was disabled at the time of development. Now the module is enabled and products started listing on the category listing pages.